# 'wcsncasecmp' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c, json

I have included file JSONValue from simpleJSON, which is used for parsing the json string.
While compiling I am getting this error that 'wcsncasecmp' was not declared in this scope.
on this line. While searching more i ot that wcsncasecmp is a GNU-specific function, I am using windows, so can anyone help me out.

```
else if ((simplejson_wcsnlen(*data, 4) && wcsncasecmp(*data, L"true", 4) == 0) ||     (simplejson_wcsnlen(*data, 5) && wcsncasecmp(*data, L"false", 5) == 0))
    {
    bool value = wcsncasecmp(*data, L"true", 4) == 0;
    (*data) += value ? 4 : 5;
    return new JSONValue(value);
}
```

.
I'll be greatful for any help.

Answer (score 2):

On windows there is `_wcsnicmp` that you can use.

More ref: [_strnicmp, _wcsnicmp, _mbsnicmp, _strnicmp_l, _wcsnicmp_l, _mbsnicmp_l](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chd90w8e.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Please define WIN32 macro in your source or in Visual Studio please add it to the project / Properties / C/C++ / Preprocessor definition.

```
#define WIN32
```

Internally it will define **wcsncasecmp** as **_wcsnicmp** like Rohan has already mentioned.
This is a known problem of SimpleJSON.

```
// Win32 incompatibilities
#if defined(WIN32) && !defined(__GNUC__)
    #define wcsncasecmp _wcsnicmp
    static inline bool isnan(double x) { return x != x; }
    static inline bool isinf(double x) { return !isnan(x) && isnan(x - x); }
#endif
```